# AutoFac - WebApi cannot Register reflected types

Tags: c#, autofac, asp.net-web-api

I'm having problems with the line "builder.RegisterInstance(Activator.CreateInstance(repoClass));".  Basically I want to reflect into a separate assembly to register my WebApiController and Types...for a plug in play architecture.  I'm new to AutoFac.  The RegisterInstance cannot resolve repoInterface in repoClass, I get a compile error. "Argument type 'object' is not assignable to parameter type repoClass."  I understand the error.  How else can I accomplish this so it works?

Thanks

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();

        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        string WebApisPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AutoFac_WebApiControllerAssembliesPath"];
        string titleLoanAsm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApi_TitleLoanAssembly"];
        Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(AssemblyDirectory.Replace("\\bin", "") + WebApisPath + titleLoanAsm);

        builder.RegisterApiControllers(asm);

        List<Type> exportedTypes = new List<Type>(asm.GetExportedTypes());

        Type repoClass = exportedTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsClass && x.Name.Contains("LGF"));

        if (repoClass == null)
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException(string.Format("No repositories found for controller"));

        Type repoInterface = repoClass.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsInterface && x.Name.Contains("LGF"));

        if (repoInterface == null)
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException(string.Format("Interface not found for class {0}. Ensure class has and interface implemented with a name that contains LGF", repoClass.Name));

        builder.RegisterInstance<repoInterface>(Activator.CreateInstance(repoClass));


        IContainer container = builder.Build();

        AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        config.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Autofac has a way to register types and have instances created by reflection.

```
builder.RegisterType(repoClass).As(repoInterface);
```

**Updated to address comments**

I think the confusion here might be that in your initial question your specifically asked about the error you were getting for the RegisterInstance call for repoClass. My answer was addressing that. The issue of MVC controllers not being found is a different issue, not really an autofac problem, but an MVC routing problem. To solve that you will need to tell the routing system where to find those other controllers. To fix that you will need to do something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" },
    new[] { "ExternalAssembly.Controllers" }
);
```

To find the value(s) to replace "ExternalAssembly.Controllers" with you will need to reflect into your external assembly similar to how your code already does and discover those namespaces.

Comment: What does a 404 have to do with Autofac registration?

Comment: 404 Not Found...look it up [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404).  Which means it's not registering correctly.  If I move the controller and types into the same assm. as the WebApi my unit test pass, if I move them out into a separate assm. and reflect the types, its not working.  As I said, I'm new to AutoFac. Maybe you could elaborate more, please?

Comment: Thanks again Nathan.  I did go the long route on this by building a dynamic runtime class.  Works great.  This at least proves my concept, now I need to genericize it.  Below is my RuntimeContainerBuilder, Answer.

Comment: I also don't think routes.MapRoute is available for WepApi.  It's config.Routes.MapHttpRoute.  A little different.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

So in my original post I was getting a compile error on the line "builder.RegisterInstance(Activator.CreateInstance(repoClass));"  This was because repoClass could not look in to repoInterface during design time.  So I created a dynamic runtime class that gets the actual types from repoClass and repoInterface at runtime, it then compiles and executes the class on the fly to return the ContainerBuilder from my Assembly.LoadFile.

```
public class RuntimeContainerBuilder
{
    public static object Evaluate(ContainerBuilder builder, Type controller, Type repoInterface, Type repoClass, Assembly assembly)
    {

        CSharpCodeProvider c = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        ICodeCompiler icc = c.CreateCompiler();
        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();

        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(AssemblyDirectory + "\\System.Web.Http.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(AssemblyDirectory + "\\Autofac.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(AssemblyDirectory + "\\Autofac.Integration.WebApi.dll");

        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(@"E:\MainTrunk2\LeadGenFramework\trunk\LeadGenFramework.Web.Api\LeadGenFramework.Web.Api.Controller.TitleLoan\bin\LeadGenFramework.Web.Api.TitleLoan.dll");

        cp.CompilerOptions = "/t:library";
        cp.GenerateInMemory = true;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        sb.Append("using System;\n");
        sb.Append("using Autofac;\n");
        sb.Append("using System.Web.Http;\n");
        sb.Append("using System.Web.Http.Controllers;\n");
        sb.Append("using Autofac.Integration.WebApi;\n");
        sb.Append(string.Format("using {0};\n", assembly.ManifestModule.Name.Replace(".dll","")));

        sb.Append("namespace LeadGenFramework.Web.Api{ \n");
        sb.Append("public class DynamicBuild{ \n");
        sb.Append("public ContainerBuilder Build(ContainerBuilder obj){\n");
        sb.Append(string.Format("obj.RegisterApiControllers(typeof({0}).Assembly).PropertiesAutowired();\n",controller.Name));
        sb.Append(string.Format("obj.RegisterInstance<{0}>(new {1}());\n", repoInterface.Name, repoClass.Name));
        sb.Append("return obj; \n");
        sb.Append("} \n");
        sb.Append("} \n");
        sb.Append("}\n");

        string s1 = sb.ToString();
        CompilerResults cr = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, s1);
        if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            //Factory.LogManager.MainProcessLogger.Info(string.Format("DynamicFormatScriptEngine:Evaluate(): Error: {0}, Code: {1}", cr.Errors[0], s1));
            return null;
        }

        Assembly a = cr.CompiledAssembly;
        object o = a.CreateInstance("LeadGenFramework.Web.Api.DynamicBuild");

        Type t = o.GetType();
        MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("Build");

        object s = mi.Invoke(o,new object[]{builder});

        return s;
    }
```

Now my WebApiConfig is like so...see the line "RuntimeContainerBuilder.Evaluate(builder, controller, repoInterface, repoClass, asm)"

```
   public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();

        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        //string WebApisPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AutoFac_WebApiControllerAssembliesPath"];
        string titleLoanAsm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApi_TitleLoanAssembly"];
        //Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(AssemblyDirectory.Replace("\\bin", "") + WebApisPath + titleLoanAsm);

        Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(AssemblyDirectory + "\\" + titleLoanAsm);

        List<Type> exportedTypes = new List<Type>(asm.GetExportedTypes());

        Type controller = exportedTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => !t.IsAbstract && typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom(t));

        if (controller == null)
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException(string.Format("Contoller not found in assembly {0}.", asm.FullName));

        Type repoClass = exportedTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsClass && x.Name.Contains("LGF"));

        if (repoClass == null)
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException(string.Format("No repositories found for controller"));

        Type repoInterface = repoClass.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsInterface && x.Name.Contains("LGF"));

        if (repoInterface == null)
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException(string.Format("Interface not found for class {0}. Ensure class has and interface implemented with a name that contains LGF", repoClass.Name));

        RuntimeContainerBuilder.Evaluate(builder, controller, repoInterface, repoClass, asm);

        IContainer container = builder.Build();

        AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        config.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }
```

The next step is to make it more generic to load assemblies into an array and setup the RuntimeContainerBuilder for each one...then builder.Build should resolve and activate everything correctly.  My end goal for this prototype is to drag and drop assemblies and have the WebApi pick them up dynamically.